# Firefox keeps losing its bookmarks

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 21.04

A question from a novice Ubuntu-user please:

When I start Firefox (version 94.0, 64 bits) from the taskbar, the program does not run, I just see the little Ubuntu logo spinning around during 15 seconds.

When I start the program a second time, the program runs but has lost all of its bookmarks.
I have to import them from the backup copy.

Next time after boot-up, the same problem. I am using Ubuntu version 21.04, problem was not there when using 20.04

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks for the reactions so far.@Algnis: how can I tell if the Firefox that I am runnng is 'deb' or 'snap' version ? Please bear in mind I am a novice..

Comment: is this the snap version or deb? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: This is a bug in the snap version

Comment: Maybe try installing the deb version `sudo snap remove firefox && sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to avoid Firefox as Snap installation and keep deb-version on Ubuntu 21.10 flavor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369778/is-it-possible-to-avoid-firefox-as-snap-installation-and-keep-deb-version-on-ubu)

Comment: @Algnis if it's really a reported bug, then a link would be helpful so the OP can monitor progress, and to justify the correct close reason.

Comment: @user535733 It "is" not a bug but it "was" a bug in 18.10 release for like a week but it was solved and now also I have experienced this bug a lot of time but it will sonn get fix again , You should try installing `sudo apt install firefox` as deb file is the best bug free

Comment: @Algnis that seems unusual, since Firefox 94 is a shiny new release; it wasn't in 18.10. If the OP is willing to do a bit of troubleshooting (which we can walk them through), they can determine whether it's really a reproducible bug or some other non-bug issue. Advising a workaround (like switching among deb vs. snap) is fine as long as we are also clear that workarounds work best in parallel with actually troubleshooting the issue and reporting any bug discovered.

Comment: @user535733 : Am I the OP (not familiar with the abbreviations yet) ? If so, what would you like me to do and when to solve the question ? I say 'when' as we might live in different time zones, I live in Holland, GMT + 1.

Comment: Open a terminal: What is the output of `which firefox` ?

Comment: @user535733: the output is /usr/bin/firefox.

Comment: A curious thing with this problem: When I start Mozilla Thunderbird (mail) BEFORE I start Mozilla Firefox, everyting looks normal, all the bookmarks are present. Starting Mozilla Firefox first results in the problem as I described: program does not run, runs after a second start but no bookmarks. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug with snap firefox

```
sudo snap remove firefox 

rm -rf ~/firefox

sudo apt update && sudo apt install firefox
```

(sudo won't be generally required to remove snaps)